Is there a way to have SDL2 use the Windows Desktop Wallpaper as a display?
I want to know if instead of opening a new window as the display, you can use the Windows Desktop Wallpaper (like an animated wallpaper or desktop pet)
I thought of just trying to create a window with the width and height and making it always at the back (similar to SDL_WINDOW_ALWAYS_ON_TOP) but such a feature does not exist. I saw a library made in rust to animate wallpaper with SDL, but it was made for Windows 10, I use Windows 11.
